# Query Document Schema in MarkLogic

Tags: sql, xml, marklogic

I would like to query the Schema definition of a Index  in MarkLogic.

How can I query that?

What would be the query to do that?

I am  talking about the Schema such as Elasticsearch Schema, with Field Types, Analyses, etc.

Please think of my question, as if I am asking how to see the column types, and column names in Oracle. How to do the same in MarkLogic? Any examples?

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic has a universal index, so there is no requirement to define a schema up front to search on specific elements or properties.

To do datatyped queries on element or properties, you can use TDE in MarkLogic 9 to define how to project datatyped values from documents in a collection into the indexes as a view over the documents.  To find out the list of columns with data types for a view, you can either query the system columns view or retrieve the TDE template from the schemas database.

In MarkLogic 8 and before, you would define range indexes on elements, properties, fields, or paths. On the enode, the Admin API can get the list of range indexes for any database. On the middle tier, the Management REST API can express the equivalent REST request.

Hoping that clarifies,

Comment: I am using Marklogic 7. I want to see the Schema, what is the command for that in query console?  Think of my question as if I am asking you how to see the column types, and names in a table in Oracle. I want to see the metadata in the Index of the Documents. 

Can you please help?

Comment: How do I see all fields / metadata of an Index in MarkLogic ?? Maybe that helps you understand my question

Comment: @FilipeMiranda notice the answer from ehennum says you don't need to have a schema.  You might not have any fields or metadata of an index defined.  They are not required.  However, if you have some defined, you can see them with admin commands such as admin:database-get-range-element-indexes, admin:database-get-range-field-indexes, admin:database-get-range-path-indexes.  To learn more, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index .  Also, while it has since been replaced by the REST admin API, you can look at pkg:database-configuration in ML 7.

Comment: I understand there is no schema, but I need to see the metadata, field names, types, etc. I understand this metadata should be available somewhow